# Discord.JS See If Role Permissions Were Added or Removed

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I have an event that triggers when a user changes a roles permissions, I already have it say which permission was updated but I don't know how to see if it was removed or added

**roleUpdate** Event:

```
                if (!oldRole.permissions.equals(newRole.permissions)) {

                    let arr1 = newRole.permissions.toArray()
                    let arr2 = oldRole.permissions.toArray()

                    let difference = arr1
                        .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
                        .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));

                    console.log(difference)
                  // would log [ 'MANAGE_CHANNELS' ] if the manage channels permission was removed or added
                 }
```

I am trying to print something like

```
 + MANAGE_CHANNELS
 - MANAGE_ROLES
 + ADMINISTRATOR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get you unstuck?

```js
const oldPerms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newPerms =          [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const addedPerms = newPerms
  .filter(p => !oldPerms.includes(p));
const removedPerms = oldPerms
  .filter(p => !newPerms.includes(p));

console.log({addedPerms});
console.log({removedPerms});
```

Comment: this works but I have this code https://pastebin.com/cEK9hcdz and when I only add a permission but not remove a permission it gives the error `MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.` but when i add a permission and remove one its fine

Comment: Looks like that's normally because `.addField()` is being called with one (not two) arguments.

Comment: it does the same with addFields, with addField it uses title, description so .addField(title, description, inline) i believe

Comment: I think you just need to change `if (addedPerms) {` to `if (addedPerms.length > 0) {` and do the same for `if (removedPerms) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Permissions#missing()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=missing). It returns all the flags that aren't present in the bitfield.

```js
// check the missing permissions in newRole
const removedPermissions = newRole.permissions.missing(oldRole.permissions)
// check the missing permissions in oldRole (meaning it just got added)
const addedPermissions = oldRole.permissions.missing(newRole.permissions)
```